# He enjoyed a drink after work, as is/does/did his wont

Tags: as

the definition of "wont" as a noun from [britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/wont):
wont - (old-fashioned) a usual habit or way of behaving:
*He enjoyed a drink after work, as is his wont* ( = as he usually or often does).

**(1a)** *He **enjoyed** a drink after work, as **is** his wont*.
Could you tell me please:
how the as-clause is made;
why "as is his wont" means "as he usually/often does";
why there is "is" in the as-clause;
why this "is" is grammatical?

What will be if we replace "is" with "did" or "does"?:
**(1b)**  *He **enjoyed** a drink after work, as **does** his wont*.
**(1c)**  *He **enjoyed** a drink after work, as **did** his wont*.

---

my sentences:
**(2a)** *His grandfather **enjoyed** a drink after work, as **does** he now*. - I know it's correct
**(2b)** *His grandfather **enjoyed** a drink after work, as **is** he now*. - I know it's incorrect

Proceeding from (2b), (1a) must be incorrect too. Why is it not so?

Comment: His ***wont*** means his *Habitual or customary usage, custom, habit* (OED). It's a peculiar word hardly used except in that rather facetious ***...as is his wont*** context *(...as is his **habit**)*. Don't use ***wont*** anywhere else - stick to ***habit, custom***. Note that *none* of your examples apart from 1a are idiomatic.

Comment: Why do you think it might be grammatical *without* the "is"?  His wont *is* X; he did X in the way that his wont is.

Answer (score 0):

"as", a conjunction can introduce a subordinate clause meaning "in the same way".

"Wont" is now no longer used in English, except in this idiom.  It is a fossil word.

But if you understand "wont" to mean "habit or way of behaving",  then it should be clear that "It is his way of behaving" is correct English but "#It does his way of behaving" is nonsense.

So a correct sentence or two is:

> Grandfather enjoyed a drink after work yesterday; he usually does enjoy a drink after work.

This has the the emphatic "does enjoy" form. What does he enjoy? it is explicit: He enjoys a drink after work.

> Grandfather enjoyed a drink after work yesterday, as is his habit.

What is his habit?  Obviously it is "enjoying a drink after work".

But " as does his habit" would be wrong and "as does his wont" would equally be wrong.

His "wont" **is** enjoying a drink.  You could not say "His wont does enjoy a drink".

Answer (score 0):

James K has explained the word *wont*, but not the syntax.

More normal syntax would be *as his wont is*. But after *as* used this way, to mean "and also", the verb/auxiliary can come before the subject, and in this particular phrase *as is his wont* is much more common than *as his wont is*.

Similarly,

> *as his father does* or *as does his father*.

> *as the rest of them did* or *as did the rest of them*.

> *as her brothers can* or *as can her brothers*.

I don't think this is a case of inversion (like *you are ready* vs *are you ready?*), because it allows only BE and bare auxiliaries (by which I mean auxiliaries without an expressed main verb).

Eg

> *as the examples will show* cannot be altered to **as will show the examples*

> *as the regulations require* cannot be altered to either **as require the regulations* or **as do the regulations require*.

But if the main verb is omitted from the *as* clause, leaving only an auxiliary, that is fine: *politeness requires your attendance, as do the regulations.*

This construction (which I think is really a form of [extraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition) rather than inversion) is only used when *as* means *and also*, not when it means *in the same way as*.

So to go back to my first example, *as his father does* usually means *in the way that his father does (whatever)*, whereas *as does his father* can only mean *and his father does (whatever) as well*.